# How to optimise a left join where both the tables are quite big (1 tb size and other 250gb)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, left-join, sparkcore

I have 8 tables, out of which one is 1 TB and other 7 are roughly around 270 GB. Each of the 7 tables needs to be left joined with the first table to get all the columns of first table and an extra column from second table which leads to 7 new columns in addition to the first table.

How can I optimize the join using Spark SQL on both an application level and other at spark config level.

PS: As all the tables have been loaded into memory, writing it again and reading it is not an option. Also we cannot go with broadcast since the size is not small.

Tried caching and joining like `spark.sql("cache table A")` all the tables and then joining

Comment: Which Spark version?  What is the execution plan that is currently generated? And lastly: what is the join criteria?.
Each new Spark version increases join performance, just using 3.5 instead of 3.4.1 in an application I'm working on increased the performance almost 3x (by automatically sorting the joined tables first along the join key - this was only visible in the physical plan)

Comment: Can you share the SQL you are using to do that. Spark version is 3.3.2

Comment: My sql's won't help you, I merely gave an example of what improvements you could have by upgrading your Spark to 3.5, the AQE has had various improvements on the versions since then.

Comment: We had just migrated to 3.3.2. I am not sure whether we will be migrating soon again to 3.5 or not.

Comment: As per your other question, you need to bring in more details - sqls used, types of fields in both tables that you are joining on etc. before anyone can help further.  If you can't upgrade you'll probably have to do more heavy lifting yourself.